# reactJs test mocked component input and reponse, where to start?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, reactjs

I am trying to test a postcode search component in my react app. Below is my component and click handler which gets data from an api using superagent. I have karma, jasmine and webpack setup and running basic component tests, but how can I mock the data and user input? I have all the json in a data file. Can I get a simple example setup using stubbing and mocking?

```
render: function () {
    return (
        <div className="mainContent add-school-page">
              <Loader loaded={this.state.loaded}>
            <div className="content has-header">
                <div className="list">
                    <label className="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                        <span className="input-label">Postcode</span>
                        <input ref="postcode" type="text" placeholder="A12 3BC"/>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div className="padding">
                    <button className="button button-block button-positive clickable"
                        onClick={this.searchByPostcode}>
                        Find School
                    </button>
                </div>
                <SearchResults results={this.state.results} />
                <br />
                <br />
            </div>
            </Loader>
        </div>
    );
},

searchByPostcode: function() {
    var postcode = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.postcode).value;
    var url = OsaApiService.buildRequestUrl('find_schools_postcode', [postcode]);
    fetch(url)
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        }).then(function (json) {
            this.setState({
                results: json.data,
            });
        }.bind(this)).catch(function (ex) {
            console.log(ex);
        });
}
```

Can anyone please tell me how I can get started?

I have tried Jest but the tests were taking forever to complete and as a watch task it took forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sample test that uses [Sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/) to create a fake server to respond to your request.  It can also be used to stub functions, which this test demonstrates by stubbing the call to `setState` on your component under test (it might be silly to stub `setSate` but I just wanted to provide an example)

```
var React = require('react/addons'),
    TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils,
    ComponentUnderTest = require('./component.js'); //whatever component you are testing

describe('ComponentUnderTest', function () {

    it('retrieves data and sets state when button is pressed', function () {
        //setups
        var server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
        server.respondWith('GET', 'find_schools_postcode', 'json_string');
        var component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<ComponentUnderTest />);
        var button = React.findDOMNode(component.refs.button); //you will need to add this ref
        var setStateStub = sinon.stub(component, 'setState'); //you don't have to stub this, you could just check that state was set afterwards

        TestUtils.Simulate.click(button);
        server.respond(); //tells the server to respond

        //expectations
        expect(setStateStub.calledOnce).toBe(true);
        expect(setStateStub.calledWith({results : 'json_string'})).toBe(true);
        //expect(component.state.results).toEqual('json_string'); //if you did not stub setState
    });

});
```

If you want to use Sinon.js in your testing suite, I'd recommend including it in your Karma configuration file:

```
frameworks: ['jasmine', 'sinon'],
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks alot. How would I test the child component search results? which displays the results state? Or any other page that has references to different components?

Comment: Could I mock the loader component in the code above? As i get the error, ReferenceError: Loader is not defined

Comment: Yes.  Take a look at this: https://github.com/tommyh/jasmine-react - in particular, the section "Replacing a component's subcomponent with a test double".  I've done this quite a bit on my project as well.